# How to override specific methods in Laravel core classes?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-8

To be even more specific and provide the most basic example of one of the methods that I would like to override is the  `ScheduleRunCommand::handle()` method.

(Specifically, would like to change the messaging for when nothing is ready to run to include a timestamp in the string.)

**ScheduleRunCommand.php**

```
public function handle(Schedule $schedule, Dispatcher $dispatcher, ExceptionHandler $handler)
{
    $this->schedule = $schedule;
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    $this->handler = $handler;

    foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {
        if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new ScheduledTaskSkipped($event));

            continue;
        }

        if ($event->onOneServer) {
            $this->runSingleServerEvent($event);
        } else {
            $this->runEvent($event);
        }

        $this->eventsRan = true;
    }

    if (! $this->eventsRan) {
        $this->info('No scheduled commands are ready to run.');
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, I **do not want** to edit this core file directly, just extend, specifically overriding that method with an updated message for when no events ran.

Comment: You are not supposed to edit the file (in your case override in other file extending the class). I have never had the need, so I cannot help you with it. But I can tell you, after working with Laravel for at least 6 years, that you should not need to do this. The only thing I can think of is that you should fork the framework core and create a pull request to add that functionality you need, something like "reading" the config and if there is a text present, use that text, instead of the default hardcoded one. But still, this is really strange to do. Why do you require a timestamp ?

Comment: Definitely don't want to overwrite the actual file. Maybe I explained incorrectly. I want to extend this class, specifically overriding this one method globally, but in the proper Laravel way.

Comment: It was a request from the project owner on this. They just wanted the current timestamp included in the message.

Comment: You could use Cronhub to monitor scheduled tasks. `thenPing` to ping cronhub. Last ping should suffice as the timestamp. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#pinging-urls https://cronhub.io/  Thought I'd share coz this could be helpful.

Comment: you can try php `trait` . write overriding function in that trait and apply it to required  class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new command that extends `ScheduleRunCommand`.

There, you extend the base command and you do whatever you want.

This command with automatically override the original command.

```php
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;

class ScheduleRunCommand extends \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand
{
    public function handle(Schedule $schedule, Dispatcher $dispatcher, ExceptionHandler $handler)
    {
        dd("test");

        parent::handle($schedule, $dispatcher, $handler);
    }
}
```

If you did all this correctly, running `php artisan schedule:run` will  execute the `handle` function of your new class:

```sh
test@project:~/code$ php artisan schedule:run
"test"
```

To specifically answer your question, since you can't only override `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`, you must copy / paste the entire `handle` function and modify the message directly:

```php
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;

class ScheduleRunCommand extends \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand
{
    public function handle(Schedule $schedule, Dispatcher $dispatcher, ExceptionHandler $handler)
{
        $this->schedule = $schedule;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->handler = $handler;

        foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {
            if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
                $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new ScheduledTaskSkipped($event));

                continue;
            }
    
            if ($event->onOneServer) {
                $this->runSingleServerEvent($event);
            } else {
                $this->runEvent($event);
            }
    
            $this->eventsRan = true;
        }
    
        if (! $this->eventsRan) {
            $this->info('[.'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'] No scheduled commands are ready to run.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this was exactly what I was looking for. I just read through the documentation as well. Just to confirm though, since I am overriding that whole method, would I just copy the method and update the part I am changing, leaving out the         parent::handle($schedule, $dispatcher, $handler); so it is not being ran twice?

Comment: It's up to you to leave it or not, if you leave it, it'll be called (so you can do something else before or after the initial `schedule:run` code), but if you remove it, only your code will be executed (then you can litterally do whatever you want, including copy/pasting the original code and changing the `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` message). Unfortunately, since the message isn't it its own method, you can't override it alone, you have to deal with the entire `handle` code :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with a example of timestamp added to the message.

Comment: Another update, the service container part is not required here, the new command you create will be registered and automatically override the base command (you inherit the `signature` property).